# SQL - Read last committed from Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you help to use the right query hint or isolation level in SQL to get the last committed values from table and ignore any on-going transaction.

Example - I have a department table with two records as below,

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Dept

CREATE TABLE Dept
(
       deptId INT PRIMARY KEY,
       deptName VARCHAR(100),
       deptDesc VARCHAR(300)
)
INSERT INTO Dept
(deptId,deptName,deptDesc)
VALUES
(101,'Computer Science And Engineering','UG and PG Courses in Computer Science And Engineering'),
(102,'Electronics And TeleCommunications','UG and PG Courses in Electronics And TeleCommunications')
```

[image]

Query Session 1 : Deletes a record from department table for id 102 but the transaction is uncommitted.

```
 BEGIN TRANSACTION 
 DELETE FROM Dept
 where deptId =102
```

Query Session 2 : Is a select to extract the data from department table, it should result with both the records (deptId - 101, 102).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `READ COMMITTED` isolation level will return the latest committed value of the deleted row only when the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option is also turned on. When the option is off (off by default with boxed SQL versions, on by default with Azure SQL Database), the second query will block when attempting to read uncommitted changes instead of returning the latest committed row version.

The `SNAPSHOT` isolation level will return the latest committed value regardless of the database `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` setting. Note that the database `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` must be enabled before one can use the `SNAPSHOT` isolation level.

I suggest using `SNAPSHOT` in this case to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

READ COMMITTED isolation level is the right transaction isolation level because "read committed is an isolation level that guarantees that any data read is committed at the moment it is read."

Details depends on the database software that is used: if SQL Server it is the default isolation level according to [SQL Server doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: No: because with READ UNCOMMITTED row for deptId 102 won't be displayed by query session 2 and this is not what is asked.